# Consequences of pouring instead of siphoning wine after primary fermention

Tags: wine, racking

Would it be a problem if I did not siphon my peach-wine-in-the-making after the primary fermentation, but rather poured it directly into the carboy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, is is a problem. After primary fermentation, one of the most important staling agents your homebrew will face is oxygen. Pouring will almost guarantee the introduction of oxygen, whereas siphoning minimizes it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a huge issue... Though oxidation is bad, it's a lot worse with beer and hopped beverages, as hop flavor can be compromised in the presence of oxygen.